# Searching for words in heading, and then deleting the heading where the word is found

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to create a code that will search a through headings in a document for a specific word, and delete the heading with the specific word, and everything associated with it.

For example:

If the heading I'm looking for is "Animals", and the subheadings are "Cats" and "Dogs" then:

**Pre Macro**

1. Text
2. Animals

   1. Cats
   2. Dogs
3. Fruit

   1. Cherries
   2. Bananas

**Post Macro**

1. Text
2. Fruit

   1. Cherries
   2. Bananas

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use code like:

```
Sub DeleteHeadingBlocks()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long, ArrRls
ArrRls = Array("Animal", "Vegetable", "Mineral")
For i = 0 To UBound(ArrRls)
  With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = ArrRls(i)
      .Style = wdStyleHeading1
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Format = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      Set Rng = .Paragraphs(1).Range
      Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel")
      Rng.Delete
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
Next
Set Rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As coded, macro assumes you're working with the 'Heading 1' Style. The array used by the macro provides for three terms ("Animal", "Vegetable", "Mineral"); you can delete/replace the unwanted terms, or add more.